# LoadError on line ["54"] of /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gruntjs, compass, susy

I'm trying to run the command for my project

```
grunt compass watch
```

in the end, I get this error

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
LoadError on line ["54"] of /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

this is my gem list (very big) and susy's there :

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.2.2.1)
actionmailer (5.2.2.1)
actionpack (5.2.2.1)
actionview (5.2.2.1)
active_model_serializers (0.8.4)
activejob (5.2.2.1)
activemodel (5.2.2.1)
activerecord (5.2.2.1)
activestorage (5.2.2.1)
activesupport (5.2.2.1)
addressable (2.5.2)
annotate (2.7.4)
arel (9.0.0)
ast (2.4.0)
aws-eventstream (1.0.1)
aws-partitions (1.138.0)
aws-sdk-core (3.46.1)
aws-sdk-kms (1.13.0)
aws-sdk-s3 (1.30.1)
aws-sdk-sns (1.9.0)
aws-sigv4 (1.0.3)
barber (0.12.0)
better_errors (2.5.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
bootsnap (1.3.2)
builder (3.2.3)
bullet (5.9.0)
bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.17.2)
byebug (10.0.2)
certified (1.0.0)
chunky_png (1.3.11)
claide (1.0.2)
claide-plugins (0.9.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
coderay (1.1.2)
colored2 (3.1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5, 1.1.4)
connection_pool (2.2.2)
cork (0.3.0)
cppjieba_rb (0.3.3)
crack (0.4.3)
crass (1.0.4)
csv (default: 3.0.4)
daemons (1.3.1)
danger (5.13.0)
date (default: 2.0.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
discourse-ember-source (3.7.0.2)
discourse_image_optim (0.26.2)
docile (1.3.1)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
email_reply_trimmer (0.1.12)
ember-data-source (3.0.2)
ember-handlebars-template (0.8.0)
ember-rails (0.18.5)
ember-source (2.18.2)
erubi (1.8.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
excon (0.62.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
exifr (1.3.5)
fabrication (2.20.1)
fakeweb (1.3.0)
faraday (0.15.4)
faraday-http-cache (1.3.1)
fast_blank (1.0.0)
fast_xor (1.1.3)
fast_xs (0.8.0)
fastimage (2.1.5)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.10.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
flamegraph (0.9.5)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
fspath (3.1.0)
gc_tracer (1.5.1)
git (1.5.0)
globalid (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
guess_html_encoding (0.0.11)
hashdiff (0.3.7)
hashie (3.6.0)
highline (1.7.10)
hiredis (0.6.3)
hitimes (1.3.1)
hkdf (0.3.0)
htmlentities (4.3.4)
http_accept_language (2.0.5)
i18n (1.6.0, 1.5.3)
image_size (1.5.0)
in_threads (1.5.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
jaro_winkler (1.5.2)
jmespath (1.4.0)
jquery-rails (4.3.3)
json (2.2.0, default: 2.1.0)
jwt (2.1.0)
kgio (2.11.2)
kramdown (1.17.0)
libv8 (6.7.288.46.1 x86_64-linux)
listen (3.1.5)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
lograge (0.10.0)
logstash-event (1.2.02)
logstash-logger (0.26.1)
logster (2.3.0)
loofah (2.2.3)
lru_redux (1.1.0)
mail (2.7.1)
mailcatcher (0.7.1)
marcel (0.3.3)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
maxminddb (0.1.22)
memory_profiler (0.9.12)
message_bus (2.2.0)
metaclass (0.0.4)
method_source (0.9.2, 0.8.2)
mimemagic (0.3.3)
mini_mime (1.0.1)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
mini_racer (0.2.4)
mini_scheduler (0.9.1)
mini_sql (0.2.1)
mini_suffix (0.3.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mocha (1.5.0)
mock_redis (0.18.0)
moneta (1.1.1, 1.0.0)
msgpack (1.2.6)
multi_json (1.13.1)
multi_xml (0.6.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mustache (1.1.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
nap (1.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
nio4r (2.3.1)
no_proxy_fix (0.1.2)
nokogiri (1.10.2, 1.10.1)
nokogumbo (2.0.1)
oauth (0.5.4)
oauth2 (1.4.1)
octokit (4.13.0)
oj (3.7.8)
omniauth (1.9.0)
omniauth-facebook (5.0.0)
omniauth-github (1.3.0)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.6.0)
omniauth-instagram (1.3.0)
omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.6.0)
omniauth-openid (1.0.1)
omniauth-twitter (1.4.0)
onebox (1.8.85, 1.8.82)
open4 (1.3.4)
openid-redis-store (0.0.2)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
optimist (3.0.0)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
parallel (1.13.0)
parallel_tests (2.28.0)
parser (2.6.0.0)
pg (1.1.4)
power_assert (1.1.3)
powerpack (0.1.2)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
progress (3.5.0)
pry (0.10.4)
pry-nav (0.2.4)
pry-rails (0.3.6)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
public_suffix (3.0.3)
puma (3.12.0)
r2 (0.2.7)
rack (2.0.6, 1.6.11)
rack-mini-profiler (1.0.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-protection (2.0.5, 1.5.5)
rack-test (1.1.0)
rails (5.2.2.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
rails_multisite (2.0.6)
railties (5.2.2.1)
rainbow (3.0.0)
raindrops (0.19.0)
rake (12.3.2)
rake-compiler (1.0.4)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
rb-inotify (0.10.0)
rbtrace (0.4.11)
rchardet (1.8.0)
rdoc (default: 6.1.0)
redis (4.0.1)
redis-namespace (1.6.0)
request_store (1.4.1)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rinku (2.0.4)
rotp (3.3.1)
rqrcode (0.10.1)
rspec (3.7.0)
rspec-core (3.7.1)
rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
rspec-html-matchers (0.9.1)
rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
rspec-rails (3.7.2)
rspec-support (3.7.1)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
rtlit (0.0.5)
rubocop (0.63.1)
ruby-openid (2.7.0)
ruby-prof (0.17.0)
ruby-progressbar (1.10.0)
ruby-readability (0.7.0)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sanitize (5.0.0)
sass (3.4.25)
sassc (2.0.1)
sassc-rails (2.1.0)
sawyer (0.8.1)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
seed-fu (2.3.9)
shell (default: 0.7)
shoulda (3.5.0)
shoulda-context (1.2.2)
shoulda-matchers (3.1.3, 2.8.0)
sidekiq (5.2.5)
simplecov (0.16.1)
simplecov-html (0.10.2)
sinatra (1.4.8)
skinny (0.2.4)
slop (3.6.0)
sprockets (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.4.0)
sshkey (1.9.0)
stackprof (0.2.12)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
susy (2.2.14)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
terminal-table (1.8.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.20.3)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tilt (2.0.9, 2.0.8)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
tzinfo (1.2.5)
uglifier (4.1.20)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.5)
unicode-display_width (1.4.1)
unicorn (5.4.1)
uniform_notifier (1.12.1)
webmock (3.4.2)
webpush (0.3.6)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
websocket-driver (0.7.0)
websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

I installed globally:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo apt-get install npm

sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

sudo apt-get install ruby-full

sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
sudo gem install bundler

npm i susy --save (and local too because in local gem list susy doesn't displayed)

gem ins hitimes
```

Local:

```
sudo npm install grunt --save-dev

sudo npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev

sudo npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev

sudo npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev

+susy
```

I tried all update. 
I put in project file Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "~> 2.4.0"
gem "sass", "~> 3.4.22"
gem "sass-globbing", "~> 1.1.5"
gem "compass", "~> 1.0.3"
gem "modular-scale", "~> 2.1.1"
gem "susy", "~> 2.2.12"
gem "ffi", "~> 1.9.25"
```

I restart my apache2 every time)

Please, help me. I am new to this field.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
Did I set everything right for grunt?